# How to insert multiple records without primary key in Fat-Free Framework

Tags: mysql, orm, fat-free-framework

I try to insert multiple records to a no PK table

```
for ($x = 0; $x < count($arr); $x++) {
    $name=$arr[$x];
    $user=new DB\SQL\Mapper($f3->get('DB'),'User');
    $user->name=$name;
    $user->save();
}
```

Finally, only one record inserted to database

I also tried `reset`, but still only one record

```
for ($x = 0; $x < count($arr); $x++) {
    $name=$arr[$x];
    $user=new DB\SQL\Mapper($f3->get('DB'),'User');
    $user->reset();
    $user->name=$name;
    $user->save();
}
```

If I add an auto_increment primary key to this table, then it is no problem.

---

Update 1:

I tested the problem again in web browser. And then I got this error

```
Internal Server Error

PDOStatement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

So I cannot execute `$db->log()` after `save()`, and now I know why there is only one record, because php stopped in first loop.

And then I enable `general_log_file`, and I found this log in the file

```
160621 18:00:53    47 Connect   dev@localhost on my_db
           47 Query SET NAMES utf8
           47 Query SHOW columns FROM `my_db`.`UserAccount`
           47 Query INSERT INTO `UserAccount` (`name`) VALUES ('uName')
           47 Quit
```

So I try to run this SQL `` INSERT INTO `UserAccount` (`name`) VALUES ('uName') `` and got no error.

I also checked `/var/log/mysql.log` and `/var/log/mysql.err` is empty.

Now I have no idea how to find out the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second attempt is correct:

```php
foreach($names as $name) {
    $user->reset();
    $user->name=$name;
    $user->save();
}
```

It's meant to work, even for mappers with no primary key.

Just bear in mind though that without a primary key, you won't be able to update `$user`. Quoted from the [docs](http://fatfreeframework.com/databases#CaveatforSQLTables):

> Although the issue of having primary keys in all tables in your database is argumentative, F3 does not stop you from creating a data mapper object that communicates with a table containing no primary keys. The only drawback is: you can't delete or update a mapped record because there's absolutely no way for F3 to determine which record you're referring to.

NB: if you're still struggling with record insertion, you can output the database log `$db->log()` to see which queries are run behind the hood.

**UPDATE:**

In order to be able to output the DB log when an error arises, you can hook on the [ONERROR](http://fatfreeframework.com/quick-reference#ONERROR) event:

```
$f3->ONERROR=function($f3) {
  echo $f3->get('DB')->log();
}
$mapper->save();// SQL error will trigger ONERROR
```

Comment: You can hook on the ONERROR event. See my updated answer. `$user->save()` triggers 2 statements: `INSERT` and `SELECT` (to reload the fresh new data). I suspect that the `INSERT` statement goes smooth but the subsequent SELECT fails, for some reason (it should not). BTW, are you using a recent version of the framework?

Comment: Ok I got it now. You've hit a bug which has been fixed a few months ago. The new release should come in a week or two and will include the patch. You can however download the latest dev version [now](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core), which will fix your issue.

Comment: ```Tue, 21 Jun 2016 10:44:41 +0000 (0.1ms) SHOW columns FROM `my_db`.`UserAccount`; Tue, 21 Jun 2016 10:44:41 +0000 (0.1ms) INSERT INTO `UserAccount` (`name`) VALUES ('uName2') Tue, 21 Jun 2016 10:44:41 +0000 (0.1ms) SELECT `name` FROM `UserAccount` WHERE```, I got this, now I understand why. It select the record after I insert, but there is empty after ```where```, so I got error, may be this is a bug?

Comment: added a fix for this.